# Is the Cartesian Product of a finite number of infinitely countable sets countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S=A_1 \times A_2 \times ...\times A_n$

Is S countable? And how do I prove it? I think the answer is yes because $A_1 \times A_2$ creates an infinite table so for n sets we would have an infinite table - just much bigger?

This is not a duplicate because no other question is for infinitely countable sets only

Comment: no - they are different

Comment: @cameron No, this is a duplicate - the fact that you ask only about infinite countable sets just means this question is a *special case* of the other, more general question.

Comment: But the answer that cam from that page is not what I will use to answer my question so it did not answer my question. I wanted to prove it with an infinite table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically this comes from the fact that
$$\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \simeq \mathbb{N}$$
which is pretty easy to prove.

Things change if you consider an infinite product of countable sets (you get $\mathbb{R}$'s cardinality)
This can easily be seen considering the decimal representation of $\mathbb{R}$. You can easily look at any real number as an element of $\displaystyle \prod^\infty C$ if $C=\{0,\dots,9\}$ (excluding infinite $9$s, but that doesn't change the cardinality).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, S is countable. You know $A_{1}\times A_{2}$ is countable, so you just need repeat the procedure $n-2$ times more. But you need note that if n goes to infinity, then S is uncountable. In this case, it is of the same cardinality as $R$.

Comment: How can I show this in the form of a proof? I wanted to use the infinite table. For example here we can see it for $A_1 \times A_2$: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable

Comment: You can prove $A_{1} \times A_{2}$ is countable, right? Next you treat  $A_{1} \times A_{2}$ as a new countable set denoted by $B$, and then apply the same proof on $B \times A_{3}$ and get $A_{1} \times A_{2} \times A_{3}$ is countable. You just repeat the procedure until $A_{n}$ is considered.

Comment: Ah yes of course - easy. Thank you

Comment: The preferred term is "countably infinite". I prefer "countable" to mean "not uncountable" so countable means "finite or countably infinite" but some people use "countable" to mean "countably infinite." A good little book I recommend is Stories About Sets by N. I'a. Vilenkin.